# ¿Alguien sabe como agregar correctamente 2 tablas SQlite en proyecto con Android Studio?

Tags: android, sqlite

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto de punto de venta en `Android`.

Al momento de crear una tabla ya puedo actualizar-eliminar-agregar-consultar productos pero al momento de crear una segunda tabla ya no me deja hacer nada de lo anterior y la app se cierra.

Si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería demasiado. Les adjunto el código que tengo en un paquete de Utilidades y que mando a llamar con la clase de `SQLiteHelper`

```
package com.example.puntodeventav3.utilidades;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Utilidades implements Serializable
{

//Constantes campos tabla articulos
public static String TABLA_ARTICULO = "articulos";
public static String CAMPO_IDARTICULO = "idArticulo";
public static String CAMPO_NOMBREARTICULO = "nombreArticulo";
public static String CAMPO_PRECIOARTICULO = "precioArticulo";

public static final String CREAR_TABLA_ARTICULO= "CREATE TABLE "
        +TABLA_ARTICULO+" ("
        +CAMPO_IDARTICULO+" TEXT PRIMARY KEY, "
        +CAMPO_NOMBREARTICULO+" TEXT NOT NULL, "
        +CAMPO_PRECIOARTICULO+" REAL NOT NULL)";

 // Constantes campos tabla ventas
public static String TABLA_VENTA = "ventas";
public static String CAMPO_IDVENTA = "idVenta";
public static String CAMPO_IDARTICULOV = "idArticuloV";
public static String CAMPO_CANTIDADVENTA = "cantidadVenta";
public static String CAMPO_DESCRIPCIONVENTA = "descripcionVenta";
public static String CAMPO_PRECIOVENTA = "precioVenta";
public static String CAMPO_FECHAVENTA = "fechaVenta";
public static String CAMPO_TOTALVENTA = "totalVenta";

public static final String CREAR_TABLA_VENTA= "CREATE TABLE "
        +TABLA_VENTA + " ("
        +CAMPO_IDVENTA+"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        +CAMPO_IDARTICULOV+"TEXT , "
        +CAMPO_CANTIDADVENTA+"INTEGER , "
        +CAMPO_DESCRIPCIONVENTA+"TEXT ,"
        +CAMPO_PRECIOVENTA+"REAL NOT NULL ,"
        +CAMPO_FECHAVENTA+"INTEGER ,"
        +CAMPO_TOTALVENTA+"REAL NOT NULL)";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para crear las tablas necesarias para tu base de datos, lo puedes realizar desde el método [onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)), que se encuentra en la clase que extiende precisamente de `SQLiteOpenHelper`, aquí debes usar los script que creaste para construir las tablas:

```
public class myClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  @Override
  public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //Crea tablas
        db.execSQL(CREAR_TABLA_ARTICULO);
        db.execSQL(CREAR_TABLA_VENTA);
  }

}
```

Recuerda que este método :

> [onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)) se llama por primera vez cuando se necesita la
>   creación de tablas.

por lo tanto debes considerar que si creaste la base de datos, esta no podrá agregar las tablas a menos que elimines el caché de tu aplicación o la elimines y la vuelvas a subir a tu dispositivo.

Answer (score 1):

mi amigo...

tu problema va a que no estas creando correctamente la sentencia sql de la segunda tabla..

tu query

```
public static final String CREAR_TABLA_VENTA= "CREATE TABLE "
        +TABLA_VENTA + " ("
        +CAMPO_IDVENTA+"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        +CAMPO_IDARTICULOV+"TEXT , "
        +CAMPO_CANTIDADVENTA+"INTEGER , "
        +CAMPO_DESCRIPCIONVENTA+"TEXT ,"
        +CAMPO_PRECIOVENTA+"REAL NOT NULL ,"
        +CAMPO_FECHAVENTA+"INTEGER ,"
        +CAMPO_TOTALVENTA+"REAL NOT NULL)";

}
```

al momento de concatenar no estas dando el espacio correcto ..  debería ser así.

```
public static final String CREAR_TABLA_VENTA= "CREATE TABLE "
        +TABLA_VENTA + " ("
        +CAMPO_IDVENTA+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        +CAMPO_IDARTICULOV+" TEXT , "
        +CAMPO_CANTIDADVENTA+" INTEGER , "
        +CAMPO_DESCRIPCIONVENTA+" TEXT ,"
        +CAMPO_PRECIOVENTA+" REAL NOT NULL ,"
        +CAMPO_FECHAVENTA+" INTEGER ,"
        +CAMPO_TOTALVENTA+" REAL NOT NULL)";

}
```

Comment: Excelente amigo ese era el problema ahora todo funciona correctamente. Muchas gracias